# How to use UnityWebRequest to make a GET request to a local NodeJs Server?

Tags: c#, node.js, unity-game-engine, networking

I am trying to make a simple HTTP:GET request using Unity to a local NodeJs Server.

My network is protected by proxy but, in this case, I am requesting to localhost.
By the way, the request works if I test it on browser or Postman.

I believe that maybe it is something related to the headers. From [UnityWebRequest.SetRequestHeader](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.SetRequestHeader.html) documentation:

> These headers cannot be set with custom values on any platform: accept-charset, access-control-request-headers, access-control-request-method, connection, date, dnt, expect, host, keep-alive, origin, referer, te, trailer, transfer-encoding, upgrade, via.

What I don't understand is why it is hitting the proxy?

Below are the scripts I used and the response.

#### NodeJs server

```
const express    = require('express');
const app  = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log('test');
  return res.sendStatus(200);
})

app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log(`Magic happens on port 8080`);
});

module.exports = app;
```

#### Unity Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class Request : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GUIStyle guiStyle = new GUIStyle ();
    string uri = "http://127.0.0.1:8080";

    void Start ()
    {
        Get();    
    }

    void Update ()
    {
    }

    public void Get ()
    {       
        StartCoroutine (SendGet ());
    }   

    IEnumerator SendGet ()
    {       
        Debug.Log (uri);
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get (uri)) {
            yield return www.Send ();
            if (www.isError) {
                Debug.Log (www.error);
            } else {                
                Debug.Log (www.downloadHandler.text);
                byte[] results = www.downloadHandler.data;
                Debug.Log (results);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
  Message.TemplateName: authenticationrequired
  Message.Language: Fallback
-->
<html>
<!-- head -->
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
  <title>McAfee Web Gateway - Notification - Authentication Required</title>
  <script src="/mwg-internal/de5fs23hu73ds/files/javascript/sw.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/mwg-internal/de5fs23hu73ds/files/system/stylesheet.css" />
</head>
<!-- /head -->

<!-- body -->
<body onload="swOnLoad();" style="background-image: url('/mwg-internal/de5fs23hu73ds/files/system/img/bg_body.jpg');">
  <!-- wrapper -->
  <div class="wrapper">

    <!-- maincontent -->
    <div class="maincontent" style="background-image: url('/mwg-internal/de5fs23hu73ds/files/system/img/bg_container.png');">

<div class="header" id="header" style="background-image: url('/mwg-internal/de5fs23hu73ds/files/system/img/bg_navbar.png');">
  Authentication Required
</div>
<!-- content -->
<div class="content">
  You must be authenticated to access this URL.<br/>

  <div class="info">
    <!-- Client IP -->
    <b>Client IP:</b> 10.0.20.188
    <br/>

    <!-- URL -->   
    <b>URL:</b> <script type="text/javascript">break_line("http://localhost:8080");</script>
    <br/>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- /content -->

<!-- action -->
<!-- spacer --><div style="height: 10px;"></div><!-- /spacer -->
<div class="action">
  <form name="ftpform" method="get" action="" id="ftpform" style="display:none;">
    <table>
      <tr><td><b>FTP User Name:</b></td><td><input type="text" name="ftpUsername" id="ftpUsername" /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><b>FTP Password:</b></td><td><input type="password" name="ftpPassword" id="ftpPassword" /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><b>Please confirm:</b></td><td><input type="button" value="Access FTP" onClick="redirectToFTP();"  /></td></tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  urlprotocol = "http";
  statuscode=407;

  if(statuscode==401 && urlprotocol == "ftp"){
    document.getElementById("ftpform").style.display = "block";
  }

  function redirectToFTP(){
    var username=escape(document.getElementById("ftpUsername").value);
    var password=escape(document.getElementById("ftpPassword").value);
    location.href = "ftp://"+username+":"+password+"@localhost:8080"
  }
</script>



<!-- /action -->



      <!-- footer -->
      <div class="footer">
        generated 2018-03-20 08:28:01
        by MWGBP01 <span class="notdisplayfalse">(10.0.1.186:8080)</span><br/>
        Autenticação: Active Directory(Autenticação: Proxy explícito)
      </div>
      <!-- /footer -->

    </div>
    <!-- /maincontent -->

  </div>
  <!-- /wrapper -->

</body>
<!-- /body -->
</html>

UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
<SendGet>c__Iterator0:MoveNext() (at Assets/Scripts/Request.cs:39)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)
```

Comment: Do you get error ? Why are you talking about headers? I just don'r understand  what's wrong in your question? Is the server suppose to return different stuff?

Comment: The request is pointing to localhost:8080 but is not received at the server. At the server console it returns nothing. The output is the clients response.

Comment: From what I've been reading, it seems like what happens is the REST backend just strips the port out for the HTTP defaults; 80 and 443 (for HTTPS).